# Unable to send the file through FTP using python 2.6

Tags: python, ftp, ftp-client

I have tried the below code and changed all the possible ways like

**storbinary** to **storlines** and **r** to **rb** and **rb+** but even though no luck in transferring files to server. Here is my sample code:

```
    from ftplib import FTP
    ftpfile = FTP('hostname')
    print "Connected with server"
    ftpfile.cwd('path of server where file need to store')
    print "Reached to target directory"
    myFile = open(inputfile, 'rb+')
    ftpfile.storbinary('STOR ' +inputfile, myFile)
    print "transferring file..."
    myFile.close()
    print "file closed"
    ftpfile.quit()
    print "File transferred"
```

The code simply runs and output all the print statement but when I check in Server there is no file created.Consider login is successfully done.

Need suggestion to achieve desired output. Thanks

Comment: You should check the response of `storebinary`

Comment: what exactly is `inputfile`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The input file is text file in my local system. e.g inputfile='c:\working\cyborg.txt'

Comment: How can you possibly know what is going on if you don't check the results of ANY of the commands. It's coding on a wing and a prayer.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony That was very nice example, anyway problem solved, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You didn't login, so you can't do anything. And are you sure `inputfile` is set?

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('hn')
ftp.login('username', 'password')
ftp.cwd('working_dir')
myfile = open(myfile.txt, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + myfile, myfile)
ftp.quit()
# No need to close() after quit.
```

Alternatively you can login on opening the connection by using:

```
ftp = FTP('hn', 'username', 'password')
```

So even better:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('hn', 'username', 'pass')
ftp.cwd('working_dir')
with open(myfile, 'rb') as f:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + myfile, f)

ftp.quit()
```

Comment: Logging is successfully done, I have updated my question

Comment: Please compare your code with the code given in problem, basically both are same, and ya its its not working yet.

Comment: True, but trying could be valueable ruling that out. Did you check file permissions?

Comment: I tried buddy, any way solved the issues and many thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass [`STOR` the filename on the *remote server*](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#STOR), as is, you are passing it a path.

You also need to use `storlines` since the file you are sending is just a plain text file.

Try this:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

local_file = r'C:\working\cyborg.txt'
remote_file_name = os.path.basename(local_file)

ftp = FTP('host', 'username', 'password')
ftp.cwd('/some/path/on/server')
ftp.storlines('STOR %s' % (remote_file_name,),
              open(local_file, 'r'))
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: Please add 0 in the string format. e.g ftp.storlines('STOR {0}'.format(remote_file_name)